# Copy to remote shared path using ansible

Tags: ansible, copy

I am trying to copy some files to a remote shared path.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Test
    copy:
     src: /tmp/log/test.csv
     dest: \\xyz_prod.com\public\app\
```

The playbook ran fine and it displayed changed=1 for the first run. When I ran it again, still it is successful and changed=0. But if I navigate to the shared location manually under the folder the test.csv file is not present. Can anyone please suggest what is wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that you now have a file literally named '\xyz_prod.com\public\app\' in the home folder of the user you are using to connect to localhost with ansible This is a not a unix path to connect to a samba share under linux.

Comment: yes you are right, is there any way to copy to remote shared path.

Comment: yes: you have to mount the share prior to copy.

Answer (score 0):

**dest** must not include URL. Quoting from [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#copy-copy-files-to-remote-locations)

> Remote absolute path where the file should be copied to.

Try the play below

```
- hosts: xyz_prod.com
  tasks:
  - name: Test
    copy:
      src: /tmp/log/test.csv
      dest: /public/app
```

For Windows remote hosts use [win_copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_copy_module.html#win-copy-copies-files-to-remote-locations-on-windows-hosts) which "`Copies files to remote locations on windows hosts`".

> To copy from a remote server

use [fetch – Fetch files from remote nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes).

---

See: [Ansible - fetch files from one remote node to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734647/ansible-fetch-files-from-one-remote-node-to-another/734712#734712).

Comment: My example shows hosts as localhost, but it can be a remote server as well. I need to copy from a remote server to a shared path. Is that possible?

Comment: Use fetch – Fetch files from remote nodes.

Comment: I need to copy from remote to another remote shared path. I tried synchronize  but it doesnt work as well, i think it is because ssh connectivity is not enabled between them

Comment: In Ansible, there is no such module to copy "remote_A <-> remote_B". Two steps are needed. (1.) fetch from remote_A (2.) copy to remote_B.

Comment: but all Ansible has to do is wait for the remote command to execute. The only reason Ansible doesn't support this is because the layers of variable expansion between Jinja/Python and YAML make constructing strings that start with two backslashes impossible  : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 2 line 1

Comment: @Smily see the link I added.